# How can I store every ordered item in a Cart List in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: listview, xamarin.android, shopping-cart

Trying to develop an item ordering system in Xamarin.Android. For showing item list, I’ve used a listView with custom adapter with Cart button in every row. Can you please suggest me which technology I should use or how can I store every ordered item in a list which will goes to my cart list activity?
Here is my itemListAdapter class :

Thank You!

[My ItemList Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdV49.png)

```
namespace Test.Restaurant.Android.Adapters
{
public class ItemListAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
List mItems;
Activity context;
private OrderDetail _OrderDetails;
private List _OrderDetailsList;

    public ItemListAdapter(Activity context, List<Item> items) : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.mItems = items;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override Item this[int position]
    {
        get { return mItems[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return mItems.Count; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        View view = convertView ?? context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ItemRowView, parent, false);
        var viewHolder = view.Tag as ItemHolder;
        var item = mItems[position];
        Bitmap myImage = ImageHelper.Bytes2Bimap(item.Image);

        // 03. List With Custom Row View           

        if (viewHolder == null)
        {

            viewHolder = new ItemHolder
            {
                itemNameTextView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.itemNameTextView),
                descriptionTextView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.descriptionTextView),
                itemImageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.itemImageView),
                priceTextView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.priceTextView),                    
                btnPlus = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.btnPlus),
                btnMinus = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.btnMinus),
                btnAddtoCart = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.btnAddToCart),
                txtQty = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.cart_product_quantity)
            };
            view.Tag = viewHolder;
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = view.Tag as ItemHolder;
        }


        viewHolder.itemNameTextView.Text = item.ItemName;
        viewHolder.descriptionTextView.Text = item.ItemDescription;
        viewHolder.priceTextView.Text = "$ " + 30;
        viewHolder.itemImageView.SetImageBitmap(myImage); 


        if (!viewHolder.btnAddtoCart.HasOnClickListeners)
        {

            viewHolder.btnAddtoCart.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {

                _OrderDetails = new OrderDetail();
                _OrderDetails.ItemId = item.ItemId;
                _OrderDetails.Quantity = int.Parse(viewHolder.txtQty.Text);
                _OrderDetails.UnitPriceInclTax = 0;
                _OrderDetails.UnitPriceExclTax = 0;
                _OrderDetails.DiscountAmountInclTax = 0;
                _OrderDetails.DiscountAmountExclTax = 0;
                _OrderDetails.PriceInclTax = 100;
                _OrderDetails.PriceExclTax = 0;


             **   //What should I Do Here???**

        **************************
        **************************
            };
        }

        return view;

    }


    private class ItemHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public TextView itemNameTextView { get; set; }
        public TextView descriptionTextView { get; set; }
        public TextView txtQty { get; set; }
        public ImageView itemImageView { get; set; }
        public ImageView btnPlus { get; set; }
        public ImageView btnMinus { get; set; }
        public ImageView btnAddtoCart { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can you please suggest me which technology I should use or how can I store every ordered item in a list which will goes to my cart list activity?

You need to pass a CartLilst(`List<OrderDetail>`) to your adapter:

```
public class ItemListAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
   ...
   List<OrderDetail> cartList;

   public ItemListAdapter(Activity context, List<Item> items, List<OrderDetail> cartList)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.mItems = items;
        _cartlist = cartList;
    }
  ...
}
```

And when user click addToCart button, add the OrderDetail to this list:

```
viewHolder.btnAddtoCart.Click += (sender, args) =>
{

     _OrderDetails = new OrderDetail();
     _OrderDetails.ItemId = item.ItemId;
     _OrderDetails.Quantity = int.Parse(viewHolder.txtQty.Text);
     _OrderDetails.UnitPriceInclTax = 0;
     _OrderDetails.UnitPriceExclTax = 0;
     _OrderDetails.DiscountAmountInclTax = 0;
     _OrderDetails.DiscountAmountExclTax = 0;
     _OrderDetails.PriceInclTax = 100;
     _OrderDetails.PriceExclTax = 0;


     //add _OrderDetail to cartList
     cartList.Add(_OrderDetails);
};
```

The list should be initialized and created in your Activity before Adapter's creation:

```
List<OrderDetail> cartList=new List<OrderDetail>();
ItemListAdapter adapter=new ItemListAdapter(this,items,cartList);
```

**Update:**

If your cart list is used quite often in your application, then I suggest you forget what I said and use a Single Pattern to store the cart list in your app:

1. Create a `CartList.cs` in your app:

   ```
   public class CartList
   {
       private static List<OrderDetail> _cartList;
       public static List<OrderDetail> Instance
       {
           get
           {
               if (_cartList == null)
               {
                   _cartList = new List<OrderDetail>();
               }
               return _cartList;
           }
           set
           {
               _cartList = value;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then you can use this CartList everywhere in your app(you don't need to pass it to your new Activity, you can get it directly in your new Activity):

   ```
   var cartList=CartList.Instance;
   ```

Comment: Hello Elvis Xia! Many many thanks from my heart!

I've applied your way. It's great! 
But there are two issues in my end.
First of all, I've used fragment for Tab(Category). Please see the linked image in my post! So, I've to passed cartList parameter in Every Fragment class. 
The problem is when I click new tab for ordering new item, the cart list Becomes empty. 
**The second issue is:** Which technology should I used to pass my cartList(orderDetails) to the new Activity.

Waiting for your valuable reply!
Thanks Again!

Comment: @Russell for your requirement, I suggest you using Single Pattern for CartList, please check my update.